# SSO into Bigcommerce

Tags: single-sign-on, bigcommerce

I am trying to write a php app to sign users into BigCommerce when they log into my website. I can't see anything in the API docs on logging in or SSO. Does anyone have a pointer to some docs on this?

Comment: you want to create a [customers](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/customers#create-a-customer)

Comment: No, creating customers is in the API docs. I want to auto login customers from my website. When new users sign up on my site, I can easily add them via the API. But how do I sign them into bigcommerce, so that when they sign in on my site they are also signed in on BigCommerce.

Answer (score 1):

well, I've tried with a trial store this issue and the only way that I found is using a hidden iframe and a simple javascript. This worked for me, See the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <title>Login BC</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    input[type="text"],input[type="password"],input[type="submit"],button{
        display: block;
        padding:4px 6px;
        margin: 12px 8px;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
    }
    input[type="text"],input[type="password"]{
        width:200px;
    }
    input[type="submit"],button{
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    #ifr{
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var redirect={
                data:{
                    url:'http://yourstore.mybigcommerce.com/login.php?action=check_login',
                    redirect:'http://yourstore.mybigcommerce.com/account.php?action=account_details',
                    login:'customerlogin',
                    pass:'customerpassword'},
                form:function(){
                    var f='<form method="post" id="bc" action="'+redirect.data.url+'">'+
                        '<input type="text" name="login_email" value="'+redirect.data.login+'"/>'+
                        '<input type="password" name="login_pass" value="'+redirect.data.pass+'" />'+
                        '<input type="submit" value="Login"  />'+
                    '</form>';
                    $('iframe#ifr').contents().find('html > body').html(f);
                    $('#ifr').contents().find('form#bc').submit();

                },
                events:function(){
                    $('#send').on('click',function(){
                        redirect.form();
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('section').append('<button id="goto">Go To Bigcommerce</button>');
                        },1500);
                    });
                    $(document).on('click','#goto',function(){
                        window.location = redirect.data.redirect;
                    });
                }
            };
            redirect.events();
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="content">
<section>
    <button id="send">Auto Login</button>
</section>
</div>
<iframe id="ifr"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone still looking to do something similar can now take a look at the JWT-based Customer Login API (https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#customer-login-api).

Combined with the customer read and write endpoints of the API, it should allow an external application to create and login a customer from an external application.